# Where are custom actions for Sourcetree saved?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'd like to share my custom actions with the rest of the team.  Where are they saved?  I can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it.

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\customactions.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users, it is under:

```
/Users/<your user name>/Library/Application Support/SourceTree/actions.plist
```